# Does testflight have upload limitations

Tags: iphone, xcode, terminal, testflight

Does TestFlight have restrictions for how often you can upload .ipa files to its API?

The reason I ask is because I am uploading via a .sh script and it works sporadically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to [ask them directly](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/emails/new), but from my experience I have never had an upload rejected except when their service is acting up.

I have used the TestFlight Jenkins plugin which uploads every successful build.

Their documentation also does not suggest there are any limits, https://testflightapp.com/api/doc/

Answer (score 0):

There is limit of 800MB per application for upload. But you can contact them and ask to increase it for your application.

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402851-testflight-faq